# Count specific character in a cell in openoffice calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a cell with some text content.
For example: "Red, shirt, size,"
I need to count how many times the comma is used in this cell.
The result should be "3"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following formula: LEN(Cell)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Cell;"YourCharacter";""))

In your case, the formula would be: LEN(Cell)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Cell;",";"").
LEN(Cell) does the following: Counts the number of characters in your cell. 
LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Cell;"YourCharacter";"")) counts the number of characters in your cell without the character ",". By subtracting the second formula, you get the number of occurrences of your character.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LEN() function as below

```
=LEN(cell)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(cell;",";""))
```